# IdentityServer4 dotnet7 produce exception

Tags: c#, migration, automapper, identityserver4, .net-7.0

when using Automaper 10.1.1, with identityserver4 and .net 7, identityserver4 is the last free version of IdentityServer and doesn't work with a higher version of AutoMapper where this issue is resolved in this link: [Issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3988).
Automapper 10 + identity server 4 + dotnet 7
simply when I hit /.well-known/openid-configuration I got this exception

```
ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Char', on 'T MaxFloat[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T])' violates the constraint of type 'T'.
System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
AutoMapper.TypeDetails+<>c__DisplayClass28_1.<BuildPublicNoArgExtensionMethods>b__10(MethodInfo extensionMethod)
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable+ConcatIterator<TSource>.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector, Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector)+MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>.UnionWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
System.Linq.Enumerable+UnionIterator<TSource>.FillSet()
System.Linq.Enumerable+UnionIterator<TSource>.ToArray()
AutoMapper.TypeDetails.BuildPublicNoArgExtensionMethods(IEnumerable<MethodInfo> sourceExtensionMethodSearch)
AutoMapper.TypeDetails..ctor(Type type, ProfileMap config)
AutoMapper.ProfileMap.TypeDetailsFactory(Type type)
AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>+<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1()
System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key)
AutoMapper.ProfileMap.CreateTypeDetails(Type type)
AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, ProfileMap options, bool isReverseMap)
AutoMapper.ProfileMap.BuildTypeMap(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ITypeMapConfiguration config)
AutoMapper.ProfileMap.Register(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal()
AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configure)
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.IdentityResourceMappers..cctor()
// Put your source/destination types here
```

I tryed all Higher versions and I get another exception because identity server 4 requires AutoMapper version>=10 and <11, in this case I got this exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!2 AutoMapper.IMappingExpressionBase`3.ConstructUsing(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,!1>>)'.
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.ClientMapperProfile..ctor()
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceOfT()
```

Comment: You can have your own fork of IdentityServer4.EntityFramework or of AutoMapper.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution

1. Just copy/paste these 2 projects and create own libraries:

[IdentityServer4.EntityFramework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework)

[IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage)

2. Bump Mapper version and fix Nullable reference types in IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage lib.
3. Remove packages from code and replace with your libraries.
   [image]

.well-known/openid-configuration now works for me.

Comment: it looks good, maybe it would be better if you make it as fork on git. for me I migrated to Keyclock.

Comment: any other alternative solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I also got this exception "The type initializer for 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers..." using .NET 8

Installing the latest version of the following packages fixed this issue for me:

- [Cnblogs.IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cnblogs.IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage)
- [AutoMapper](https://%3CPackageReference%20Include=%22AutoMapper%22%20Version=%2212.0.1%22%20/%3E)

Answer (score 3):

I also saw this problem yesterday - spent a lot of time looking for a solution but couldnt.
`I decided to downgrade .net to 6.0` then it worked - though, the requirements of IS4.EF.Storage mention support to .net 7.0

> Maybe you should look at [Duende.IdentityServer](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver)

This is new company by creators of IS4. Probably the issue has been resolved there. Switching from IS4 to Duende shouldnt be difficult due to their similarity

Comment: Thanks, yes I am already using .net6 and everything works fine for me, the problem with Duende is that it's not for free, and I think this will not be solved on IS4 at least in a short term bcs it's out of support

Comment: @KarimMoghnieh , as far as I know that Duende is free for personal use.

Comment: You will need to pay for Duende if your income more than a 1\`000\`000$ , seems to be.

Comment: This is the right approach for fixing this issue properly. Or go with DuendeServer. Downgrade solution to .NET 6 and every NuGet package to version 6. And it will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

As an update from the answer by @Tapac, you can use this package which has the updated AutoMapper

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cnblogs.IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/

Also, this is discussed in detail here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/5486

Answer (score 1):

You can install new version of Automapper directly to your top level projects and solution would use them.

Comment: Only in theory. In practice that is what causes the second exception. Presumably it is something that you never actually tried.